# XSD regex not matching

Tags: regex, xsd

I'm creating an XML file based on someone else's XSD specification, but I just can't figure out why it doesn't validate.

Here's the rule:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyStringType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:pattern value="[^\t\n\r]*[^\s][^\t\n\r]*" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

in which I read the pattern as follows:

- `[^\t\n\r]*` match anything that is not tabs, newlines or <strike>spaces</strike> returns 0 or more times
- `[^\s]` match anything that is not a space
- `[^\t\n\r]*` match anything that is not tabs, newlines or <strike>spaces</strike> returns 0 or more times

and following example of one of the many mismatching xml:

```
        <Zipcode>3506 RT</Zipcode>
```

It's not matching `3506 RT` (or `3506RT` for that matter, and many other things I would expect to match) according to xmllint, with the following error:

```
element Zipcode: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.reeleezee.nl/taxonomy/1.23}Zipcode': [facet 'pattern'] The value '3506 RT' is not accepted by the pattern '[^\t\n\r]*[^\s][^\t\n\r]*'.
```

Any hints on what I'm not interpreting right? (I don't understand the strictness of their NonEmptyStringType btw, I would just use .+)

---

As requested, here's the zipcode declaration:

```
<xs:element name="Zipcode" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" rse:CanIgnore="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Postcode</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="NonEmptyStringType">
            <xs:maxLength value="10" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

as you can see, this links back to the pattern in NonEmptyStringType (first rule posted above)

Comment: could you show us 'Zipcode' element declaration?

Comment: This is puzzling. I tried using that expression on various strings, and they all seemed to work just fine. Can you come up with any strings that pass the validation? I wonder if there are any hidden characters messing things up (or different character encoding?

Comment: Yup, <Street> has the same `NonEmptyStringType`, and in my test file that is 'Hoogeinde'. Which matches. If I put that in the zipcode field, it passes. I can't see any logic in what passes and what doesn't:

Comment: '2' fails, 'Varik' passes, 'Varik2' passes, '2222Varik' passes , '2222Vk' fails

Comment: You need at least 3 non numerical characters?

Comment: This looks fine to me.  I think it's a bug in your validation tool... they are often buggy in edge-cases.  OK, just checked: `xerces` accepts it; `xmllint` fails. I've found several times in the past that xerces is correct, and xmllint has problems in unusual cases.  And this regex is unusual. http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation and http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html also accept it (though I can't vouch for them).

Comment: The strings that pass all have at least three letters in them. The zip code that failed `3506 XT`, as well as `2` and `222Vk` have fewer than three. Perhaps you can try some other strings to see if that conjecture holds. I'm thinking @13ren is right - that this is a bug in the validation tool. Can you turn it off (validate against something other than `nonEmptyStringType`)?

Comment: @13ren, thanks for checking against another validator (which I should've thought of myself). If you can put this in an answer, I'll except it. I'll have a word with the authors of the schema :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex looks fine to me. I think it's a bug in your validation tool... they are often buggy in edge-cases.

OK, just checked: xerces accepts it; xmllint fails (I see you were using xmllint). I've found several times in the past that xerces is correct, and xmllint has problems in unusual cases.  And this regex is unusual. (I have to say, I actually love xmllint, it's really fast, but the xsd spec is huge, complex and confusing, and the xmllint folks haven't nailed all the edge cases yet).

The two online validators I tried also accept it: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation and http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

BTW: for xerces, I downloaded their java version, and found their class `jaxp.SourceValidator` the best tool for validating. But I believe it's the same code already in java.

---

*EDIT* I did some more tests in xerces, to ensure that the regex *can* fail (i.e. it is active). It fails if there is a `\n` anywhere. (same for `\t`, though I didn't test `\r`).

Checking the spec, `\s` is defined as `[#x20\t\n\r]`
(in [this table](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#nt-MultiCharEsc)). That makes it clear that the regex is saying you can't have `\t`, `\n` or `\r` *anywhere*. But you *can* have as many literal space characters (`#x20`) as you like, provided they aren't *all* space characters (i.e. there is at least one non-space char, to match that `[^\s]` - btw could notate that as `\S`).   Xerces confirms this: all spaces gives an error.

Maybe they want to allow space literals (both padding and interspersing), provided there is some value in there (i.e. not *all* spaces).

Answer (score 1):

`[^\s] match anything that is not a space`

but your input string `3506 RT` has space!

I think that is why it is failing :) 
because `[^\t\n\r]` passed `3506` after which you don't expect a space character `[^\s]` but it appears ! And `[^\t\n\r]` also passes because the next set of chars is `RT`

So what you should have declared is:

```
<xs:pattern value="[^\t\n\r\s]*[\s][^\t\n\r\s]*" />
```

Now this will allow

1. Anything that is `NOT \t, \n, \r and \s` to be more strict about pattern you would like to add + which allows string only if it has atleast one non-whitespace character in the beginning.
2. A space character: we can have it as optional by declaring like this `[\s]?` .. where ? allows once or not at all. so space character can't repeat.
3. again Anything that is  `NOT \t, \n, \r and \s`.

`<xs:pattern value="[^\t\n\r\s]+[\s]?[^\t\n\r\s]*" />`

Actually it can be made more strict by validating number and alpha characters rather than having `[^\t\n\r\s]` declaration..

Hope it helps! And let me know if any question troubling you.

Comment: `3506 RT` can validate against the pattern in 6 ways, for example, the chars in `3506 R` are all not `\t\n\r` and the remaining char `T` is not a space, leaving zero chars for the last part to match.  The 6 ways it can match are for each of the 6 non-space chars coinciding with the `[^\s]`).  BTW: it *is* a weird regex and I haven't yet been able to imagine what their intention with it is (assuming it's not a mistake). So maybe you're right that it's a mistake, but OP doesn't have control over it, and can't get it changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe \r is a space, it's a carriage return (similar to \n newline). You might want to replace that with \s or just the actual literal " ".

Comment: sharp eye! That was a typo/thinko on my side. I cannot replace anything in the xsd declaration though, since that's not mine... I just have to make sure I pass!